# windows/cmd running exe on multiple files

Tags: cmd

I am pretty sure this may have been answered before but I do not know how to search for it. I have tried but cannot find the exact behaviour I am looking for.

Anyway, my query is as follows:

- On windows/Cmd window
- I have a program.exe that runs as folows "program.exe file.ext"
- Can I, with a single command run "Program.exe file.ext" for all files on a certain path that have a certain ext?

i.e.:

program.exe file1.ext
program.exe file2.ext
etc.

Thanks,

Yona

Comment: `for %%i in (*.ext) do program.exe "%%i"`. See `for /?`

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I found it fails with '%%i', you have to do '%i' instead

Comment: yes, `%` on command line, `%%` in batch files.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Stephan this is the correct answer:

> for %i in (*.ext) do program.exe "%i"

Or if you have the files on a folder:

> for %i in ("Folder name\"*.ext) do program.exe "%i"

(PS 1: Use %% on batch files)

(PS 2: Notice the " " on the folder name in case it has space or many characters).